# How do I write a JSON object to file via Node server?

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, post, http-status-code-404

I am using Angular for the front-end and attempting to write a JSON object to a file called 'post.json' in the same directory as index.html. I can make it work using PHP but I want to know how do it with Node.js. I have looked at a lot of posts online but maybe I am not understanding how http POST actually works and what settings the server needs to write to file from an Angular app. How do I write to file from the Angular app and what settings does the node server need?

Code in the Angular file:

```
// Add a Item to the list
$scope.addItem = function () {

    $scope.items.push({
        amount: $scope.itemAmount,
        name: $scope.itemName
    });

    var data = JSON.stringify($scope.items);

    $http({
        url: 'post.json',
        method: "POST",
        data: data,
        header: 'Content-Type: application/json'
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, 
    function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });

    // Clear input fields after push
    $scope.itemAmount = "";
    $scope.itemName = "";
};
```

This is the node server file:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(8080);

fs = require('fs');
fs.open('post.json', 'w', function(err, fd){
    if(err){
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log("successful write");
});
```

I am then getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Did you set up the server itself? Set up routes, that is?

Comment: Sounds like that is what I need. I'll look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example of Node.js server using [Express.js](http://expressjs.com) framework (in case you are not limited to 'connect').

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  fs.writeFile(__dirname+"/post.json", req.body, function(err) {
    if(err) {
       return console.log(err);
    }
    res.send('The file was saved!');
  }); 
});

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8080!');
});
```

In your angular controller specify explicitly the url:

```
 $http({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080',
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
    header: 'Content-Type: application/json'
})
```

**EDIT:**

Removed `body-parser` middleware for simplification.

Comment: This works, I just added `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');` instead of `res.send('Hello World!');` and then created a folder named static which contains all my static files then added this `app.use(express.static('static'));` to node.js server file. Thanks. Looks clean.