# How to save to local files from browser?

Tags: javascript, file, web, browser, localhost

I created a prototype about a tool that would analyze source code and write metadata about it in files to be read by a web application served locally.

Now I need to specify details about how I'll implement it. The data would need to go both ways, first the backend write to file and the frontend read from file, second the frontend write to file and backend read from file.

My question is about how I do the second part, saving from the browser to local files, knowing that I will be serving the page locally.

I've found this api https://web.dev/native-file-system/ that might be what I need, but it's pretty new and requires permission from the user. I guess I can do it differently because I'll serve it locally.

For more context, here's the [video of my prototype](https://forms.gle/5vbfc54MRXcBodKc7)

Comment: I don't know much about this API, but I did just see a video from web.dev that went into a bit of detail and had some code samples. I hope it helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXCT3htg9nk&list=PLNYkxOF6rcIBhuGsbO6t8-OBE5-fVPe7K&index=7

Comment: I think you need to activate some flags to use native-file-system api

Comment: Yes, it's true, and it is a another reason that I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: I'm thinking about using [http-server](https://github.com/http-party/http-server) to do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35495687/3646180), but it still uses the Express.js framework, what I don't need.